# Single collection with a key vs multiple collections

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I am designing the DB for a project, where, I am sure that I would not be querying for data belonging to multiple values of a key `x` at the same time.  All queries will be for sure for a given value of `x`.  Is it better to create a single collection having an index for `x`, or is it better to create multiple collections having `x` as part of the collection name?

I want to optimize storage space, and well as ensure reasonable read query performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is single collection at this case.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why?

Comment: Because with this design it's more probably that active data (with indexes) stays at the memory. So, DB response faster to your queries.

Comment: But, will it not increase the storage space, since, now an additional index needs to be created on ```x```?

Comment: One collection + one index is less than multiple collections what have the mandatory _id index and own extents. And wiredtiger can compress (better) collection with multiple documents, than multiple collections with single document.